# How would I get post data out of bootstrap select options?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label" for="setup">Setup Cost:</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gbp"></span></span>
                <select class="form-control" id="setup">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                    <option>75</option>
                    <option>100</option>
                    <option>150</option>
                    <option>200</option>
                    <option>250</option>
                    <option>300</option>
                    <option>350</option>
                    <option>400</option>
                    <option>500</option>
                </select>

        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm using the following code in a form that I'm trying to pass data to another page that formats a HTML email with the details of the form, however, I can't seem to echo the POST data of any of my select options. I'm fairly new to PHP and bootstrap so would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the select tag a name, like so:

```
<select class="form-control" id="setup" name="setup"></select>
```

Now you can get the value in php by that name, like so:

```
echo $_POST['setup'];
```

Comment: Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `<select>` tag a `name` attribute, without a `name` attribute the browser does not consider a field to be a candidate for sending to the server when a form is submitted

```
<select class="form-control" id="setup" name="setup">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give select tag a name and you need to give value in option tag like

```
<select class="form-control" id="setup" name="setup">
    <option value='0'>0</option>
    <option value='50'>50</option>
</select>
```

Now you can get value
echo $_POST['setup'];